# Target resolution for a game (Android)

Tags: android

So, we're developing a game and the artist asked in what resolution is he supposed to prepare the graphics.

I've done some research 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

and from what I gather I should ask him for 1920x1200 resolution graphics, and then
from these I can prepare graphics for lower resolution devices.

That would be a major screw-up if I asked him for wrong resolution art so I want to make sure.
Is that the case ? When he does these 1920x1200 graphics, am I going to be able to produce all the other popular sizes/resolutions with no problem ? My biggest fear are ratio differences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clipping isn't a concern, you can use 1920x1200. However, you'll have to do some editing for different aspect ratios, like you guessed.

I would create a large one for each target aspect ratio, if that is your concern. The most common ones are probably 16:9, 15:9, 4:3, but you might want to do some research on what your *focus* devices are.

If you have one in each aspect ratio, it makes scaling easier. However, the artists I've worked with generally provide me more than that, since a general scale doesn't always look good in a l/mdpi setting. They normally work with vector graphics for the base images, and then can scale to whatever resolution and put it in a raster format. You might want to ask your artist about that, though, since I'm not much of an expert on it. All I know is he sends me pretty pictures in many different resolutions.

All in all, though, aspect ratio isn't very important for *most* graphics. A fullscreen background, maybe, but all your UI components should be fine with just an mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi version.

Answer (score 1):

Please use larger graphics. The accepted answer is alright for year 2013 when it was posted, but there are devices with 2560x1600 now and graphics don't look sharp and crisp on them.

If you want to support everything properly and make your life easy, ask the artists to supply everything in at least 2733x2134 pixels (for fullscreen images like backgrounds, etc.) You can use smaller sizes for sprites (just calculate which percentage of the screen it would occupy).

BTW, that 2733x2134 might look odd, but it was carefully calculated. See the details here:

http://bigosaur.com/blog/31-android-resolutions-definite-answer